# Solve zero of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, roots

This is the equation I have:

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi t+\frac{\pi }{2}}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)=0$$

Also the variable t has a requirement $0\le t\le \frac{3}{2}$. I have tried $\frac{\pi t+\frac{\pi }{2}}{2}=\frac{\pi t}{2}$ but when trying to solve for t, it t gets removed. I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: When does $\sin \left(  \phi + \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \sin \phi$?

Comment: This equation is not an ordinary differential equation. You must use the next formula $\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure @mjw

Answer (score 3):

Just use the identity
$$
\sin (a+b)=\sin(a) \cos (b) +\cos(a) \sin (b).
$$

Then, in your case, you reduce your equation to:
$$
\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}x) (\tfrac{\sqrt{2}-2}{2})+\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos (\tfrac{\pi}{2}x)=0
$$
or, equivalently
$$
\tan y = \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2-\sqrt{2}}
$$
where $y=\tfrac{\pi}{2}x$.

This yields that the unique solution in $(0,\tfrac{3}{2})$ is $x=\tfrac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $(\pi t/2)=x$. Use the derived formula $$\sin A-\sin B=2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac {A+B}{2}\right)$$
to get
$$\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-\sin x=0
\Rightarrow2\sin\frac{\pi}{8}\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{8}\right)=0\\\Rightarrow\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\left[ t+\frac{1}{4}\right]\right)=0$$
We know that $\cos (n\pi)=0$ (only) for all odd multiples of $\pi/2$ i.e.,
$$t+\frac{1}{4}=2n+1\Rightarrow t=2n+\frac{3}{4}\quad (n\in\mathbb{Z}).$$
This is the general solution. If the minimum positive value is desired, put $n=0$.

**NOTE.** If you can't recall this formula, derive it. Hint:
$$\sin(X+Y)-\sin(X-Y)=2\sin Y\cos X$$
Put $X=(A+B)/2$ and $Y=(A-B)/2$.

Comment: " We know that $\cos (n\pi)=0$ (only) for all odd odd multiples of $\pi$". This is not correct: $\cos(\pi)=-1$.

Comment: @Jotabeta right my bad. i meant odd multiples of $\pi/2$